# Iterating Arrays: another approach

Tags: javascript, for-loop, iteration, while-loop

It bugs me that you call the for-loop for iterating Arrays the best approach, because inside the array you need to get the iterated element manually. I found another approach that suits me better in some cases:

```
var data=['test1', 'test2', 'test3'], item=0, n=0;
while ((item=data[n++])) {
   // here you can use item instead of data[n]
}
```

Regards, LX

Comment: That approach will only work if the array contains a last "sentinel" element that evaluates to `false` (e.g. `null`, `0` or the empty string), though.

Comment: What do you mean by *inside the array you need to get the iterated element manually*? How does `item=data[n++]` solve it?

Comment: because inside the loop I do not need to address data[x], but can use item.

Answer (score 4):

Will fail if array contains 0, false, null or other "falsy" values.

While will exit in the middle of array

Comment: I know. This construct ist mostly to iterate node collections.